# What it means to "be captured by this"?

Tags: word-meaning

"There's no objective standards for what platforms might be captured by this." he said, "it creates a very subjective process that is open to abuse."
[<sup>(Source)</sup>](https://www.thestar.com/politics/federal/2021/02/17/senator-wants-to-use-canadas-copyright-law-to-make-companies-like-facebook-and-google-pay-for-news.html)

What it means to "be captured by this"?

Comment: What does 'this' refer to in the first sentence?

Comment: "this" is a proposed change to Canadian law to make companies like Facebook, Google, Youtube ***pay*** existing "news" companies for content. The quoted speaker (a law professor at the University of Ottawa) is saying the proposal isn't properly thought through, and there's no telling ***which*** other companies might be caught up in something that's presumably only *intended* to apply to a few of the big Internet platforms (but could spread uncontrollably).

Comment: ***captured = caught up = ensnared** (accidentally)*. The proposed legislation is *intended* to make wealthy Facebook pay poor struggling local newspapers and the like for news content (gathered by reporters paid by that newspaper). But it might end up forcing small companies (or even individual *bloggers* and such) to pay big outfits like Newscorp & Reuters if they refer to items that are "in the news".

Answer (score 1):

Q. **What it means to “be captured by this”?**

---

I would suggest it means **"to take something into your possession, especially by force":** I would also suggest that it is not used literally in this case but to imply  catching something in a rather aggressive manner.

---

There's no objective standards for what platforms might be captured by this

**There's no relevant standards for what particular technology might be caught by this**

**capture**; verb; to take someone as a prisoner, or to take something into your possession, especially by force:

**platform**; noun; COMMUNICATIONS; a method of communication or entertainment, for example television, radio, or the internet:

---

Ref CED [Capture](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/capture?q=captured) [Platform](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/platform?q=platforms)

Comment: I think the speaker (a law professor at the University of Ottawa) should probably have used ***caught up in*** rather than ***captured by***. As you say, the latter implies "in a rather aggressive manner", which itself implies "as a **deliberate** act". The professor isn't necessarily claiming that anyone would intentionally extend the scope of the proposed legislation to apply to cases where it's not "appropriate" (though there would always be that risk). He's just saying that (because of "the law of unintended consequences") it's likely "misapplications" ***will*** occur.

Comment: Although I am not aware of what he was trying to say or what this change in law relates too. I would in general agree with your comments. I have often heard & seen captured used when caught might have been the better word.

Comment: It's a small point, and of course the professor might (deliberately or unwittingly) be implying that "dark forces" within the legislature and the executive are ***already*** planning to extend the scope of the planned legislation. After all, he does refer to the potential for future ***abuse*** (which connotes "volition" far more than does the alternative ***misuse***). But since you'd mentioned "aggressive" behaviour, I thought it was worth flagging this up for the benefit of non-Anglophones who might not otherwise pick up on the full implications.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably need to provide quite a bit more context to allow for an definitive answer.
But assuming "this" refers to a check or question about a system the "captured by this" would mean systems that fail to meet the standard the check requires.

In a physical analogy, consider using a sieve in a stream. The small holes in the sieve allow stones to be captured while the water and very small objects pass through.

The next part of your sentence states "it creates a very subjective process" so likely the check that "this" refers to is not well defined perhaps something like;

> Ensure the application does not perform unnecessary personal data processing.

This can be abused in either direction. The app blocked because an arbitrary authority declares something it does as "unnecessary personal data processing" or the developer can state that some processing is "essential" and may not have to provide evidence.